# How long does it take to get your checked-in bag at London Gatwick airport?

Tags: luggage, short-connections, missed-flights, lgw

I have booked, rather to my own surprise on reviewing my itinerary, two separate tickets (that part was inevitable, discount carrier Norwegian Air is first carrier) with 2:05 connection between airlines at LGW, South Terminal. That's counting on the first flight arriving nearly on time, which was probably a mistake. (Most recent performance is 0:40 late, 1:10 late, and 3:50 late, which I bet involved turning on the afterburners to avoid the compensation due at 4:00.)

Our luggage is small enough to be taken as a carry-on, but in theory it is probably over Norwegian's 10kg weight limit, which includes the additional laptop bag. I feel I will have to make a game-time decision whether to check bags, adding to time needed to transfer, or hope they aren't using scales at the gate. **How much additional time will baggage reclaim take, given that we have to go through immigration (USA passports) anyway? Will the bags likely be waiting once we clear the passport examination?** (We don't need to re-check the bags, as British Airways' weight allowance is much larger.)

Comment: It is pretty much unpredictable. You can be in and out in 15 minutes, or you can wait 30 mins for the luggage, and another 30 mins at the customs control, depending on how many other flights arrived right before yours. From personal experience and gut feeling, once you cleared immigration, 45 minutes give you 90% chance to make it.

Comment: If your final destination isn't in the UK or Ireland, you may not have to go through UK passport control at all if you only have hand luggage. This would save you even more time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Norwegian does connections at Gatwick at least between their own flights. But not necessarily interlining with BA, of course.

Answer (score 2):

> How much additional time will baggage reclaim take, given that we have to go through immigration (USA passports) anyway? Will the bags likely be waiting once we clear the passport examination?

Passport queues for non-EEA residents can vary from one or two minutes to over an hour. It is not easy to give an estimate, especially as you do not mention what time you are arriving. Bags should all be delivered within thirty minutes although delays are hardly uncommon.

If you are connecting to an international flight (excluding to Ireland and to the Channel Islands), you have your onward boarding pass, and you have hand baggage only, you can use the Flight Connections channel to bypass immigration, bag claim, and customs. You will go through security and into the departures hall. If you can I would advise against checking your bag.

If you do have to pick up your bags you can use the [Gatwick Connects service](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/flying-in/gatwickconnects/) to recheck your luggage back in and collect your boarding pass directly, it's in the luggage hall. This may save you a few minutes.